# create an image view in android with arbitrary shape

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i want to create an image views as above in XML or JAVA for android, i have tried many times but not possible.
Help  is greatly appreciated.

[image: This picture shows a profile in a social network]

Comment: This seems broad. I think you should ask a question specifically. By looking at the image you have provided, we could not state this is the answer. It needs learning lots of things to create such.

Comment: It is better if you could learn more about Android Layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the described background by below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/your-drawable" android:gravity="center" android:alpha="0.1"/>
    </item>

    <item android:top="300dp"
      android:bottom="-300dp"
      android:left="0dp"
      android:right="-300dp">
        <rotate
          android:fromDegrees="-10"
          android:pivotX="0%"
          android:pivotY="100%">
            <shape
              android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid
                  android:color="?android:colorBackground"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: and what are magic numbers like `-300dp` `300dp` etc? do you think it will work when using those numbers?

Comment: @pskink Yes, definately.

Comment: no, it will not - again why 300? why not 400 or 500?

Comment: I have implemented the same and it is working, Yes if it is sizing issue then we can surely manage by defining in dimen file.